# Nuget Custom package Restore from URI on Build Server

Tags: visual-studio-2017, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, nuget-package-restore

Could anyone suggest me the best way to restore custom Nuget packages on a build server after a TFS build definition is triggered. 
Whether to pass the packagesource URI through nuget.config, or restore it using powershell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could install your custom Nuget packages by right clicking the project in VS -- select `Manage NuGet Packages`, and check in the `packages.config` file.

Then, in your TFS build definition, add a **NuGet Installar** task before VS Build task to restore the packages.

[image]

Comment: I have added custom packages as package source in nuget.config file and also added the source in the nuget installer task in build definition. This worked as expected.